# Anti Aliasing Issue with Wireframe modifier

Tags: wireframe, motion-blur

New blender user here - loving it so far. I'm running into an anti aliasing issue on a wireframe modifier object during render. Here is a breakdown and what’s happening:

1. I added a wireframe modifier to a tetrahedron. I'm using Eevee and added bloom & motion blur. I was initially getting some serious antialiasing that would show up in some frames (particularly frames within a shrinkwrap animation of the tetrahedron morphing into another shape—see pic).

   [image]

   [image]
2. I played around with upping the Sampling but the thing that seemed to solve the issue was a. changing the Motion Blur to "Start on Frame" instead of "Center on Frame" and b. decreasing the Motion Blue shutter from .5 to .1

But I'm still noticing this sort of vibrating anti aliasing, particularly on the center line (it almost vibrates when animated—it's a 360 rotate animation):

[image]

Any thoughts on how to reduce this if possible would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a chance to affect this "blocky" bloom. It's seems to be a price of eevee to be real-time. What can you see are bloom "samples" and there doesn't exist a way to increase this resolution (from what I know).

In general I would say it wasn't designed for such a strong effect. The same as for antialiasing - the issue is raising more clearly on lines with low angle where stepping is easier to see.

[image]

What I tried ... there isn't relationship with another parametr (like scene volumetric, sampling or what ever) that can increase stepping ... the only one panel that can affect the result is Bloom itself.

**So try to tweak values there ... probably you can find some setup with better result.**

And ... I don't think **Motion blur** can fix that ... in some situation it can reduce appearance thanks to blur direction, but make it worse in other situations.

---

**Some kind of hack** ... you can try *Volume object* with **Mesh to Volume** modifier + **Bloom**. The idea is to use volumetric where you can easily increase steps into very smooth result, and bloom use just as last soft touch to get glowing without high values.

Add *Volume* object and add *Mesh to Volume* modifier as source choose your tetrahedron. Decrease *Exterior Band Width* to 0.02 and switch to *Voxel Size* and decrease value to 0.01.

*Volume* object only ...
[image]

Material - *Principled Volume* shader with increased *Emission Strength* to 2
[image]

*Volume* object + original tetrahedron object + *Bloom*
[image]

*Render Properties > Sampling* - increase value to something like 256

... or all this is illusion and I was wrong :)

Comment: Thank you so much vklidu! I'll play around with the suggestions.