# Motion Blur in EEVEE creating strange artifacts

Tags: eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

I'm new to Blender and I've been practicing some simple animation.

When I render out an animation EEVEE random frames through the animation gets this issue.

[image]

When I turn of motion blur I get no such issue.

[image]

Comment: What issue? Show us a good frame for comparison. (Okay, I’ll go ahead and zoom around in the image to see if I can… no, not that kind of zoom around. Chewy is STILL fixing the hyperdrive)

Comment: Update: I still see no problem. What are you talking about?

Comment: I'll update the image when I get home from work for a comparison.

Comment: This is a video of the issue, I removed the BG to see if that was causing it but this was not the case. 

Video here: https://youtu.be/hU2PkM24Fmc

Comment: After further testing it seems to be connected to the motion blur.

Comment: Have not seen the video, but are you talking about the ghost scratches to the left of the Earthoid that match its shape?

Comment: That's right, kills the background world space too.

Comment: Ok. IDK what’s causing that, but if you add that description to the question you might get better answering results (most stackexchangers do not follow external links out of personal policy against spammers).

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have had similar problems and I wonder if you've already found the solution to your problem. But I found this, [Anti Aliasing Issue with Wireframe modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220835/anti-aliasing-issue-with-wireframe-modifier). I changed the position to "Start on frame", instead of "Center on frame" and set the Shutter to .1. It fixed my issue. I also tried turning it back up to .5 after i turn it down to .1, and it no longer has artifacts.